# C++ How to add dynamically two different types of datas string and int

Tags: c++

Can someone help me to dynamically add two types of datas: string and int which I would like to sort it later?

Full Source Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

struct Datas
{
    string text;
    int number;
};

void print( string::size_type n, string const & s )
{
    if( n == string::npos ) {
        cout << "not found\n";
    } else {
        cout << "found: " << s.substr( n ) << '\n';
    }
}

map < char, int > make_pythagorean_map()
{
    return {
        { 'A', 1 },
        { 'a', 1 },
        { 'B', 2 },
        { 'b', 2 },
        { 'C', 3 },
        { 'c', 3 },
        { 'D', 4 },
        { 'd', 4 },
        { 'E', 5 },
        { 'e', 5 },
        { 'F', 6 },
        { 'f', 6 },
        { 'G', 7 },
        { 'g', 7 },
        { 'H', 8 },
        { 'h', 8 },
        { 'I', 9 },
        { 'i', 9 },
        { 'J', 1 },
        { 'j', 1 },
        { 'K', 2 },
        { 'k', 2 },
        { 'L', 3 },
        { 'l', 3 },
        { 'M', 4 },
        { 'm', 4 },
        { 'N', 5 },
        { 'n', 5 },
        { 'O', 6 },
        { 'o', 6 },
        { 'P', 7 },
        { 'p', 7 },
        { 'Q', 8 },
        { 'q', 8 },
        { 'R', 9 },
        { 'r', 9 },
        { 'S', 1 },
        { 's', 1 },
        { 'T', 2 },
        { 't', 2 },
        { 'U', 3 },
        { 'u', 3 },
        { 'V', 4 },
        { 'v', 4 },
        { 'W', 5 },
        { 'w', 5 },
        { 'X', 6 },
        { 'x', 6 },
        { 'Y', 7 },
        { 'y', 7 },
        { 'Z', 8 },
        { 'z', 8 }
    };
}

map < char, int > make_simpleeng_map()
{
    return {
        { 'A', 1 },
        { 'a', 1 },
        { 'B', 2 },
        { 'b', 2 },
        { 'C', 3 },
        { 'c', 3 },
        { 'D', 4 },
        { 'd', 4 },
        { 'E', 5 },
        { 'e', 5 },
        { 'F', 6 },
        { 'f', 6 },
        { 'G', 7 },
        { 'g', 7 },
        { 'H', 8 },
        { 'h', 8 },
        { 'I', 9 },
        { 'i', 9 },
        { 'J', 10 },
        { 'j', 10 },
        { 'K', 11 },
        { 'k', 11 },
        { 'L', 12 },
        { 'l', 12 },
        { 'M', 13 },
        { 'm', 13 },
        { 'N', 14 },
        { 'n', 14 },
        { 'O', 15 },
        { 'o', 15 },
        { 'P', 16 },
        { 'p', 16 },
        { 'Q', 17 },
        { 'q', 17 },
        { 'R', 18 },
        { 'r', 18 },
        { 'S', 19 },
        { 's', 19 },
        { 'T', 20 },
        { 't', 20 },
        { 'U', 21 },
        { 'u', 21 },
        { 'V', 22 },
        { 'v', 22 },
        { 'W', 23 },
        { 'w', 23 },
        { 'X', 24 },
        { 'x', 24 },
        { 'Y', 25 },
        { 'y', 25 },
        { 'Z', 26 },
        { 'z', 26 }
    };
}

map < char, int > make_gfive_map()
{
    return {
        { 'A', 7 },
        { 'a', 7 },
        { 'B', 8 },
        { 'b', 8 },
        { 'C', 1 },
        { 'c', 1 },
        { 'D', 2 },
        { 'd', 2 },
        { 'E', 3 },
        { 'e', 3 },
        { 'F', 4 },
        { 'f', 4 },
        { 'G', 5 },
        { 'g', 5 },
        { 'H', 6 },
        { 'h', 6 },
        { 'I', 7 },
        { 'i', 7 },
        { 'J', 8 },
        { 'j', 8 },
        { 'K', 9 },
        { 'k', 9 },
        { 'L', 1 },
        { 'l', 1 },
        { 'M', 2 },
        { 'm', 2 },
        { 'N', 3 },
        { 'n', 3 },
        { 'O', 4 },
        { 'o', 4 },
        { 'P', 5 },
        { 'p', 5 },
        { 'Q', 6 },
        { 'q', 6 },
        { 'R', 7 },
        { 'r', 7 },
        { 'S', 8 },
        { 's', 8 },
        { 'T', 9 },
        { 't', 9 },
        { 'U', 1 },
        { 'u', 1 },
        { 'V', 2 },
        { 'v', 2 },
        { 'W', 3 },
        { 'w', 3 },
        { 'X', 4 },
        { 'x', 4 },
        { 'Y', 5 },
        { 'y', 5 },
        { 'Z', 6 },
        { 'z', 6 }
    };
}

map < char, int > select_map( int choice )
{
    switch( choice )
    {
    case 1:
        {
            return make_pythagorean_map();
        }
    case 2:
        {
            return make_simpleeng_map();
        }
    case 3:
        {
            return make_gfive_map();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int cho = 0, d;
    char o;
    string phrasetwo;

    while( 1 )
    {
        system( "cls" );
        cout << "You want to use: " << endl << "1) Pythagorean Gematria" << endl << "2) English/Simple Gematria" << endl << "3) Extra: " << endl << "Gematria with G = 7" << endl << endl;
        cin >> phrasetwo;
        istringstream asd( phrasetwo );

        if( !( asd >> d ) || asd >> o )
        {
            system( "cls" );
            cout << "You want to use: " << endl << "1) Pythagorean Gematria" << endl << "2) English/Simple Gematria" << endl << "3) Extra: " << endl << "Gematria with G = 7" << endl << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cho = stoi( phrasetwo );
            if( cho <= 3 && cho >= 1 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    auto m = select_map( cho );

    string::size_type n;
    ifstream input( "words.txt" );
    ofstream output( "results.txt" );
    string str, phrase;
    int counter = 1, cnt = 0, choice = 0, chosennum = 0, asd = 0, f = 0, x;
    bool flag;
    char c;

    while( 1 )
    {
        system( "cls" );
        cout << "You want to check:" << '\n' << "1) Number" << '\n' << "2) Phrase" << endl;
        cin >> phrase;
        istringstream s( phrase );

        if( !( s >> x ) || s >> c )
        {
            system( "cls" );
            cout << "You want to check:" << '\n' << "1) Number" << '\n' << "2) Phrase" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            choice = stoi( phrase );
            if( choice <= 2 && choice >= 1 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    switch( choice )
    {
    case 1:
        {
            cout << "Which number do you want to check?: ";
            while( 1 )
            {
                cin >> phrase;
                istringstream s( phrase );

                if( !( s >> x ) || s >> c )
                {
                    cout << endl << "Which number do you want to check?: ";
                }
                else
                {
                    chosennum = stoi( phrase );
                    break;
                }
            }
            cout << endl << "All words found: " << endl;
            break;
        }

    case 2:
        {
            do
            {
                flag = false;
                cout << "Which phrase do you want to check?: ";

                cin.ignore( numeric_limits < streamsize >::max(), '\n' );
                getline( cin, phrase );

                for( int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++ )
                {
                    if( isdigit( phrase[ i ] ) )
                    {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
                cout << endl;
            } while( flag == true );

            for( char charr: phrase )
            {
                chosennum += m[ charr ];
            }
            cout << '\t' << phrase << " in gematria = " << chosennum << endl << endl << "All words found: " << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    output << "All words found: " << endl;

    int tablica[4], b = 0, kupa;
    string str2;
    string::size_type G;

    while( getline( input, str ) )
    {
        int sum = 0;

        n = str.find( ',' );
        G = n;

        if( n != string::npos )
        {
            do
            {
                tablica[ b ] = n;
                b++;
                n = str.find( ',', n + 1 );
            } while( n != string::npos );

            str2 = str.substr( tablica[ 3 ] + 1 );
            kupa = stoi( str2 );
            str.resize( G );
            b = 0;
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ )
        {
            if( ( ( int ) str[ i ] ) > 127 || ( ( int ) str[ i ] ) < 0 )
            {
                str.clear();
            }
        }

        for( char charr: str )
        {
            sum += m[ charr ];
        }

        if( sum == chosennum )
        {
            cout << "No[" << counter << "]: " << str << "(" << sum << ")" << '\n';
            output << "No[" << counter << "]: " << '\t' << str << " = " << sum << endl;
            cout << "TEST LICZBY: " << str2 << endl << kupa << endl;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\n You have found: " << ( counter - 1 ) << " words" << '\n';
    output << "\n\n You have found: " << ( counter - 1 ) << " words" << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

In this part of code is `counter` which is increasing and is a number of found words. This is the dynamically size which I want to define

```
        if( sum == chosennum )
        {
            cout << "No[" << counter << "]: " << str << "(" << sum << ")" << '\n';
            output << "No[" << counter << "]: " << '\t' << str << " = " << sum << endl;
            cout << "TEST LICZBY: " << str2 << endl << kupa << endl;
            counter++;
        }
```

And I want to add dynamically these two types of datas: `string str` and `int kupa`. I want to add it dynamically in this part of code which is shown above.

For example `string str` is `somerandomtext` and `int kupa` is `4` and it will pair somehow `somerandomtext, 4` and next one `string str` is `againsomerandomtext` and `int kupa` is `22` and it will pair somehow
`somerandomtext, 4`
`againsomerandomtext, 22` etc in one vector or something

Thanks for answers. Love you all <3

Comment: what does it mean to "dynamically add a string and int"? Please reduce your code example to only the necessary part ([mcve]) and include the expected output in the question

Comment: Have you looked at std::variant?

Comment: do you mean you have a string `"3"` and an integer `5` and you want to get `8` as result? Or perhaps `"35"` ?

Comment: You might just want a std::tuple or std::pair

Comment: No. Lets say user gives you his age and his name for example John, 24 and next one user is giving you again his name and age for example Mark, 31. The number of users is unknown. Thats why I want to add it dynamically. Stack these datas because I want to sort it later by age number and it would look like 
John, 24
Mark, 31

Answer (score 0):

> For example string str is somerandomtext and int kupa is 4 and it will pair somehow somerandomtext, 4 and next one string str is againsomerandomtext and int kupa is 22 and it will pair somehow somerandomtext, 4 againsomerandomtext, 22 etc in one vector or something

You can use a [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), more specifically a `std::pair<std::string,int>` to store a string together with an integer:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>> data;
    data.emplace_back("somerandomtext",4);
    data.emplace_back("againsomerandomtext",22);
    for (const auto& e : data) {
        std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second <<'\n';
    }
}
```

However, `std::pair` is actually meant to be used in cases where you don't really know what is the two, ie you cannot give them a better name. Whenever you can give them a better name, you should do so:

```
struct name_and_age {
     std::string name;
     int age;
};
```

and then use a `std::vector<name_and_age>`.

Comment: First solution is perfect for me. How to fast sort results by these numbers 4, 22 etc? From higher to lower

Comment: @babidi if you want to sort them according to the `int` then put the `int` first and use `std::sort`

Comment: @babidi https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: Sort works when Im using this method
```sort(Datas.begin(), Datas.end());

    for (const auto& e : Datas)
        {
            cout << e.second << " " << e.first <<'\n';
        }```
And its sorts like 1...2...3...4
But when Im using this and want to sort by 4...3...2...1
```sort(Datas.begin(), Datas.end(), greater<int>());

    for (const auto& e : Datas)
        {
            cout << e.second << " " << e.first <<'\n';
        }```
I have error, why?

Comment: @babidi `greater<int>` is the wrong type. If you want to sort `std::pair<int,std::string>` you need `greater<std::pair<int,std::string>>`